# After inserting one row for Ukrainian Language, the field in app page is showing ????? even after removing the row

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2016

There is a TEXT_TRANS table which contains the translation of a specific word and they contain same textid but different languageid. Suppose there is a row in TEXT_TRANS table for the Name column 'Mohan' which has a specific textid and languageid . For Ukrainian language there will be another row for Name column 'мохан' which will have same textid as of english but different languageid. So I have inserted one row for Ukrainian language but forgot to put N before ukrainian word because it will show ?????. Then I updated correctly by putting N before the ukrainian word. However, The field is still showing as ?????? even when I deleted that row for Ukrainian language.

Comment: What do you mean by "forgot to put N before ukrainian word because it will show ?????"

Comment: Other Ukrainian texts work? The database was updated correctly? Testable by adding a new text with other key. Then it is probably caching in the persistence layer. Restart the application. Still? Try first storing 'foo' and then the right text.

Comment: check the datatype. It should be nvarchar instead of varchar

Answer (score 1):

To store and select Unicode character in database you have to use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR. You need to be sure that column has correct datatype.